# TryTake performance on BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, performance, blockingcollection

I have a program which sometimes runs significantly slow.

I tried Teleriks Justtrace to find out, what could possible cause a hang of the application.

A non UI thread (therefore I believe it's not really the cause of the hang) does async. get objects (Enqueues workitems) and deques it to do some work.

Enqueue:

```
        public void EnqueueObject(WorkUnit workunit)
        {
            try
            {
                workUnits.Add(workunit);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }
        }
```

Dequeue:

```
        public WorkUnit Dequeue()
        {
            try
            {
                WorkUnit aWorkUnit  = null;
                workUnits.TryTake(out aWorkUnit, 1000);
                
                return aWorkUnit ;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                // 
            }
            return null;
        }
```

`TryTake` was used to check for an abort of current work (instead of the `BlockingCollection` `Complete` method which just throws some errors when called - I don't want to use errors for program flow)

Call to dequeue:

```
 while(!isStopped)
 {
     ProcessWorkItem(Dequeue());
 }
```

Up to here it looks quite simple.

The problem is, that Teleriks JustTrace shows, that the line `workUnits.TryTake(out aWorkUnit, 1000);` takes 30% of the total execution time of the program.

How can this be?

With more details it shows that inside the `TryTake` `System.Threading.Monitor.Wait` takes up all the time - I thought the Wait would send a thread to sleep, so it does not consume something during the wait. Where is the error in the thought?

Comment: It should be fine. But are you adding lots of items to the queue? Or is it really waiting for a second each time? By the way, if your use of BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding() causes errors, you must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Have you tried making `TryTake` wait inifitely for an element to take? Code: `workUnits.TryTake(out aWorkUnit, -1);`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you have a Take() in a loop, and then use CompleteAdding() the Take() will throw an InvalidOperationException . (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx ). Exceptions are not wanted here. The amount depends. I tried to add only 3000 items to the queue.

Comment: @dzienny TryTake was choosen to avoid the infinitive wait. Otherwise Take() would have been enough.

Comment: @MatthewWatson it shows the load also if only "workUnits.TryTake(out aWorkUnit, 5000);" is done and nothing is added.

Answer (score 1):

I think that infinite while may be an issue because it will try to get it wether there is something or not all the time.
You could try

```
BlockingCollection<WorkUnit> workUnits = new BlockingCollection<WorkUnit>();
Thread _workerThread;
_workerThread = new Thread(() => {
   foreach (WorkUnit workunit in workUnits.GetConsumingEnumerable())
   {
       doWork(workUnit);
   }
});
//code/threads adding workUnits with workUnits.Add(workunit);
workUnits.CompleteAdding();
_workerThread.Join();
```

I'm running this piece of code with minimal processing overhead on 16 processes with 4 threads each for 64 100% running threads +16 queueProcessingThreads out of 72 threads and the remainnig 8 threads of the cpus are on 30% so it is just doing the minimum processing work to maintain those 16 queuesProcessingThreads running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `workUnits.TryTake(out aWorkUnit)` without the timeout parameter. And then, you should modify `while` loop to look similar to this:

```
 while(!isStopped)
 {
    WorkUnit wu = Dequeue(); 
    if(wu != null) 
       ProcessWorkItem(wu);
    else
       Thread.Sleep(40);
 }
```

Also, if you are running this code on a UI thread it will make your UI unresponsive. You should use for example [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the operation. Here's the description of `BackgroundWorker` class from MSDN documentation:

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution.

Comment: With an empty list the following happens: Out of 100 ms total computing time of the programm, TryTake is shown to take 18 ms (~20%), the percentage keeps stable even if programm runs for some minutes. (for example if it runs 5 minutes 1.182 computing time is shown, and out of it 234 is the TryTake)

Comment: yes it is running in another thread - that is why i mostly think this should not cause the hang. I'm just curious why the telerik trace tool shows this as item which most cpu usage. Having 20% load just whith a Take-operation (independend wether it takes something or not) seems to be too high

Comment: The bad thing is that Take() seems to Call TryTake() and therefore shows the same problem.

Comment: @Offer From "Code Complete" _[Jon] Bentley also reports the case of a team that discovered that half an operating system's time was spent in a small loop. They rewrote the loop in microcode and made the loop 10 times faster, but it didn't change the system's performance-they had rewritten the system's idle loop._ It just may be your case :)

Comment: yes it could be. My problem can be: waht does JustTrace report? In the former job RedGate'S Ants seem to be better to really find issues, but I don't really know how accurtae JustTrace is. I think the hang of the system was removed (a lock in another place which was not shown as hotspot). But it is still an ambivalent feeling if at a point of code most cpu usage is shown...

Comment: I'm confused, is this answer suggesting to replace the event-based Take with a more polling like loop? Isn't that an antipattern, especially with small sleep intervals?